# Java to access pci-modem

Tags: java, com, communication, modem, pci-bus

I have a pci-modem in my laptop and I tried to run a program that opens the port and  configures it.I get an excepcion while doing it, I think that it can't see the port, even though it is on COM3. Is there any way of doing it in java?

The error I get is noClassDefFoundError. It says the SerialPortEventListener class isn't found. I'm using rxtxcomm. I tried using javax.comm but it doesn't find the port either.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

A NoClassDefFoundError indicates that you're missing a JAR file from your classpath, specifically the one that is holding SerialPortEventListener class.  Check your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the [installation instructions](http://www.captain.at/howto-java-serial-port-javax-comm-rxtx.php) for rxtxcomm ? Note you have to handle a library and a jar file. You need to specify a system library path for the native component.

You may find that you get the 'no class def found' if the appropriate .jar *is* found, but it can't find the corresponding native library to load.